# Laravel 5 Blade Templating Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to understand laravel's basic blade template engine, but I can't seem to get past a basic example, and the documentation doesn't seem to be of much help. Any suggestions?

```
   -views
     --landing.blade.php
     --navbar.blade.php
```

landing.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('navbar')
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

navbar.blade.php

```
@extends('landing')
@section('navbar')
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
@stop
```

The only thing that renders when I visit landing.blade.php is "Hello World".

Comment: probably you want to use `@include` instead of `@yield`

Comment: That results in nothing rendering.

Comment: how does your code look like now?

Answer (score 2):

navbar.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

landing.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    @include('navbar')
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please read the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating) on using Blade but specifically how to yield content.

You can also make it more flexible with `section` and `extends`.

Comment: You're right, of course, but you should probably add an explanation about _why_ so that OP can learn easier what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that's not in the documentation though.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Not going to give you answer because rude. Have nice day.

Comment: of course it's in documentation, ``Note that views which extend a Blade layout simply override sections from the layout...``, you override section, however you didn't render navbar anywhere